# Groupby one column and rearrange another string column based on a vector of string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

For the following toy data `dd`, I try to groupby `langue` column and rearrange `char` column based on the order of vector `char_order`:

```
dd <- data.frame(langue = c('English', 'French', 'English', 'French'),
                 char = c('world', 'monde', 'hello', 'bonjour'), 
                 x = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
                 y = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
dd

char_order <- c('hello', 'world', 'bonjour', 'monde')
dd %>% 
  group_by(langue) %>% arrange(.by_group = TRUE)
```

Out:

```
  langue  char        x     y
  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 English world       8     1
2 English hello       9     1
3 French  monde       3     1
4 French  bonjour     9     2
```

But I wish to get a result as follows:

```
  langue  char        x     y
  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 English hello       9     1
2 English world       8     1
3 French  bonjour     9     2
4 French  monde       3     1
```

How could I achieve that in **pipe (%>%)** using `dplyr` or other packages? Sincere thanks.

Comment: `dd %>%arrange(langue, factor(char, char_order))`

Comment: I tested, your code could achieve same result as @Park's, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may set factor levels

```
dd %>%
  mutate(char = factor(char, levels = char_order)) %>%
  group_by(langue) %>% arrange(char, .by_group = TRUE)

  langue  char        x     y
  <chr>   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 English hello       9     1
2 English world       8     1
3 French  bonjour     9     2
4 French  monde       3     1
```

Comment: just commented on something similar